# splitting an stereo camera frame into left and right sensor frame

Tags: opencv, c++11, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am working with a stereo camera and capturing frames with opencv. The captured frame contains image from left and right sensor joined together in one image. So with a resolution of 640*480, I have an image with 1280 columns and 480 rows. The first 640 columns belong to one sensor and the 641 to 1280 to the second sensor. I need to split it into left and right frame. I am trying to crop the left and right frames but i am getting an error. I have removed the extra code and showing only the problem area.

```
  cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
  Mat fullframe = frame(Rect(0, 0, 1280, 480 )); //only to check that I have 1280 columns and 480 rows.and this line works
  Mat leftframe= frame(Rect(0,0,640,480)); // This also works
  Mat rightframe= frame(Rect(641,0,1280,480));// this gives an error
```

The error comes in cmd.exe and is :

```
    OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x +roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <=m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 323
```

Which I don't understand. If I have 1280 columns, why can't I just keep the 641 to 1280 columns. Anything above 0 gives the same error, So even if I use:

```
    Mat rightframe= frame(Rect(1,0,1280,480)); // I still get same error
```

Any help?

Comment: [`cv::Rect`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#a5a41149f4b012b9f323b5913454375a1) -- the third parameter is width. If you start at column 641 and try to get additional 1280 columns out of a 1280 column image, half of them will be from outside of the original image. That's an error (for fairly obvious reasons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the documentation of Rect(x, y, width, height) where x, y are coordinates of top left corner. Accordingly it should be `Mat rightframe= frame(Rect(641,0,640,480));// this gives an error`.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV typically assumes that the top and left boundary of the rectangle are inclusive, while the right and bottom boundaries are not. Therefore I suggest your code should look like this.

```
cap >> frame;
Mat fullframe = frame(Rect(0, 0, 1280, 480 ));
Mat leftframe= frame(Rect(0, 0, 640, 480));
Mat rightframe= frame(Rect(640, 0, 640, 480));
```

I know it's a bit late, but it may help others that have will a look on this question in future.